# How to resolve Fatal Exception in vb.net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, fatal-error

I am working on a application and I wrote the code below,

```
Public Function CreateDatatable(ByVal SqlQuery As String, ByVal strTable As String, Optional ByVal OrderbyField As String = "") As DataTable

        If InitDB() Then
            Try
                Dim sqlAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter()
                Dim dt As New DataTable()
                If SqlQuery = "" Then SqlQuery = "Select * from " & strTable & IIf(OrderbyField <> "", " order by " & OrderbyField, "")
                Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(SqlQuery, MySQLCon)
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 18000
                sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd
                dt.TableName = strTable
                sqlAdapter.Fill(dt)
                CreateDatatable = dt
            Catch ex As Exception
                ServiceLog.WriteEntry("CreateDatatable Exception:" & ex.Message)
            End Try
        Else
            CreateDatatable = Nothing
        End If

    End Function
```

After running the code this error occurred.

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException={"Fatal error encountered during
>   command execution."}
>      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
>      at AgilityNewsService.clsDataware_MySQL.CreateDatatable(String SqlQuery, String strTable, String OrderbyField) in C:\ISMSCleanDesktop\DesktopBkup_Tue10-22-2013\AgilityNewsService\AgilityNewsService\AgilityNewsService\clsDataware_MySQL.vb:line 48

How to resolve the above error?

Comment: Post the value of `SqlQuery`

Comment: Yes, knowing what values you supplied as parameters to this method would be extremely helpful, since at the moment we have no idea what the SQL looked like.

Comment: you need to be more specific on the error message. Please supply a complete exception with stacktrace! What line does it fail on? What is MySQLCon, SqlQuery, strTable, OrderbyField?

Comment: Hi all i am edited total error code,please help me

Comment: sqlAdapter.Fill(dt) ...here error is occur

Comment: from here,

 http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,591975,592003#msg-592003

it says that you should try extending net_read_timeout and net_write_timeout variables from your DB

Comment: hi malky ,how write code extending net_read_timeout and net_write_timeout variables from DB?